# Request body different from submitted data

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, express

I'm working on a React app that has a form, and sends it to an Express route to post the data to an API. An example from the API documentation expects the form data object to look like this:

```
var form_data = {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "p[7]": "7",
      "status[7]": "1"
      "p[12]": "12",
      "status[7]": "1"
    };
```

The `p[7]` and `p[12]` indicates what list id to add the user to. I'm getting the active lists from the API just fine and populating a select menu for the user to pick from. When the user submits the form, I console log the data, and it all appears as it should:

```
{email: "testemail@example.com", p[10]: "10", p[9]: "9"}
```

As you can see the response has the correct ID's output that I selected from the menu. When I submit the form and send it off to the Express route to push it to the API the data suddenly changes. From the console log on the Express server:

```
{ email: 'testemail@example.com', p: [ '9', '10' ] }
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with sending this data. Here is my method to send the data from the React app:

```
sendData(){
    let formData = {
      email: this.state.email_address
    }

    let selectValues = this.state.value.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < selectValues.length; i++) {
      formData[`p[${selectValues[i]}]`] = selectValues[i]
    }

    // outputs as expected 
    console.log(formData)

    // Send the form data.
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var _this = this;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200 && response.status === 'OK') {
          _this.setState({ type: 'success', message: 'We have received your message and will get in touch shortly. Thanks!' });
        }
        else {
          _this.setState({ type: 'danger', message: 'Sorry, there has been an error. Please try again later or send us an email at info@example.com.' });
        }
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/send-job-signup', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(this.requestBuildQueryString(formData));
  }
```

I stripped out all the API connections from the route but its pretty straight forward:

```
.post('/send-job-signup', (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.body);

  res.send(req.body)
} )
```

Any ideas what would cause the response to push the data into one `p` key? Thanks for your input!

Comment: What does `this.requestBuildQueryString` do?

Comment: this is the normal behavior of https://github.com/ljharb/qs (express body parser use this library)

Comment: @pfg outputs as expected as separate items, not one.

Comment: @Peter I'm just using ES6 functions, not the `qs` library?

Comment: express use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser what use the qs library

Comment: @Peter ah i see you edited your response, that makes sense. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? The API requires them to be separate and looking at the docs I'm not 100% sure how I could override this functionality.

Comment: I am not sure i think you can try to use the raw source of the post body, and pass it to json parse yourself

Comment: or you can convert it back: `var newP = {}; p.forEach((p_) => newP[p_] = p_);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @Peter mentioned in the comments, the root of the issue was the `qs` library used by `body-parser`.

The key to preventing this was setting `extended: false` in `urlencoded`. So in `index.js` of my Express app ([See docs on body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended)):

```
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
  }))
```

This kept each `p` key separate allowing the API to do its thing.